# Disable ERB handler in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

Is there a way to disable the ERB handler in Rails.

This may sound silly but we're migrating to SLIM and want to
prevent that some lazy developers still use ERB.

Comment: I'd start by poking at ActionView::Template::Handlers; that's what registers the erb handler. The easiest might be to monkey-patch a deregister and de-register it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As far as I can see there's no way to `unregister` a template handler.

But we can do it by means of a hack.

the `ActionView::Template::Handlers::ERB` has the following line;

```
self.class.erb_implementation.new(
  erb,
  :trim => (self.class.erb_trim_mode == "-")
).src
```

So lets break it, for fun.

We'll add an initializer `config/initializers/no_erb_allowed.rb`

```
class NoErbAllowed
  def initialize(*args)
    raise "ERB is not allowed"
  end
end

ActionView::Template::Handlers::ERB.erb_implementation = NoErbAllowed
```

Any view that tries to use ERB will then raise the error

```
ActionView::Template::Error (ERB is not allowed):
```

Comment: @UchennaOkafor, some people, me included, prefer to avoid the verbosity of erb.

Answer (score 1):

I think this ought to work:

```
handlers = ActionView::Template::Handlers.class_variable_get :@@template_handlers

handlers.delete :erb

ActionView::Template::Handlers.class_variable_set :@@template_handlers, handlers
```

Basically this gets the `@@template_handlers` hash from `ActionView::Template::Handlers`, removes the `:erb` key (which points to the ERB handler) and writes it back to the class.

This would probably go in an [initializer](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/configuring.html#using-initializer-files). It needs to load after `ActionView::Template::Handlers` (obviously) but before the handlers themselves are loaded so I *think* it belongs in a `to_prepare` or `before_eager_load` initializer, e.g.:

```
module YourApp
  class Application < Rails::Application
    config.before_eager_load do
      handlers = ActionView::Template::Handlers.class_variable_get :@@template_handlers

      handlers.delete :erb

      ActionView::Template::Handlers.class_variable_set :@@template_handlers, handlers

    end

  end
end
```

Hope that's helpful!